# How do I get the string between the first and last underscore in a given string?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get the string between the first and last `_` in a given string but is not working for me. Take a look to the following table with examples of input => output:

```
gbox_asset_locations_list => asset_locations
gbox_company_list => company
gbox_country_states_cities_list => country_states_cities
string_company_1_string => company_1
```

I have tried the following:

```js
$(function() {
  var str = 'gbox_asset_locations_list';
  var result = str.substring(str.lastIndexOf('_') + 1, str.lastIndexOf('_'));
  
  $('body').append(str + ' => ' + result); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

But is not working since I didn't get the proper output, can any help me to get this working? What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you using `lastIndexOf()` to locate the *first* underscore?

Comment: @kevinternet is the string after the `=>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wouldn't it be easier to use a regular expression?

```
$(function() {
  var str = 'gbox_asset_locations_list';
  var result = str.match(/_(.*)_/)[1];

  $('body').append(str + ' => ' + result); 
});
```

The regex matches 'first an underscore, then as many characters of any kind as possible, then another underscore'. You then take the 'many characters' as the result.

Answer (score 2):

try that :

```js
var str = 'gbox_asset_locations_list';
var result = str.substring(str.indexOf('_') + 1, str.lastIndexOf('_'));

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(function() {
   var strs = ['gbox_asset_locations_list', 'gbox_company_list', 'gbox_country_states_cities_list', 'string_company_1_string']

   var res = [];
   var _str;

   strs.map(function(item, idx) {
     _str = item.substring(item.indexOf('_')+1, item.lastIndexOf('_'));
     res.push( _str);
     document.querySelector('#results').innerHTML += res[idx] +'<br>';
   }.bind(this));
}())
```